# Merge several large wordlists into one removing duplicates with PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have huge dictionaries that contains duplicates and wondering how to correctly merge these wordlist into one removing duplicates with a PowerShell script.

Eg

file1:

```
aaaaa
abcd
bbbb
1111
```

file 2

```
abcd
1111
hjii
okom
bbbb
```

output file

```
aaaaa
abcd
bbbb
1111
hjii
okom
```

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Thanks I will try but I'm not sure this will work correctly

Comment: unfortunately doesn't work

Comment: the file are vey large 2.1GB and 3.8 GB are the smaller that I have tried to merge, and unfortunately cannot upload them

Answer (score 0):

I am unsure how fast this will be with the large files like you mention but this Powershell code should do the trick

```
# Assuming files are named list1.txt and list2.txt. change as needed
Get-Content "C:\list*.txt" | Select-Object -unique > "c:\foo.txt"
```